# Not translated model parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Excerpt from my config/locales/models/de.yml:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      guestbook:
        message: Nachricht
```

The database exactly is the meaning of messages, but the message of the validation error instead of "Nachricht" written "Messages". What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup in config/application.rb the following:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

Comment: I'm realy use it. Everything else works. Not translated exactly that.